# use strncmp without defining size_t n

Tags: c

example : strncmp("John", "Johny")
it seems this example still works without the 3rd parameter.

Can anyone explain this a little bit? I can't find any explanation in the C documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to include the relevant header file:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Please enable all your compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: Thank you! After I include the header file, it comes with the error...But how the strncmp function still works without including the header file?

Comment: @Nathan see my comment in PeterM answer. Without the function declaration, c89 is implicitly declaring the function as: `extern int strncmp();`. `()` means the function takes an unspecified number of argument.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess `undefined behaviour`.   Where the C system expects to find the `n` parameter, it is finding by happenstance a number that is larger than the lengths of both of your test strings.

In other words you lucked out partly due to ignoring warnings.

Comment: Assuming he is using `gcc` which is by default C89 + GNU extensions or MSVC which is C89, implicit declaration is a part of the language. The implicit declaration is `extern int strncmp();` which is fine for `strncmp`.